# Should I remove `included` models that are already in `data` in a JSON API response?

Tags: json, serialization, json-api

Let's suppose I have a model called `topics` which is self-referenced (a topic *belongs to* a topic via its `parent_topic_id`).

So, I have a topic called `sports` and a children topic called `basketball`.

The JSON API response is currently being serialized as:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "topics",
      "id": "sports",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Sports",
        "show-role-title": null,
        "created-at": "2017-04-16T21:19:25.000Z",
        "updated-at": null
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "/topics/sports"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "topics",
      "id": "sports-basketball",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Basketball",
        "show-role-title": null,
        "created-at": "2017-04-16T21:19:25.000Z",
        "updated-at": null
      },
      "relationships": {
        "parent-topic": {
          "data": {
            "type": "topics",
            "id": "sports"
          }
        }
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "/topics/sports-basketball"
      }
    }
  ],
  "included": [
    {
      "type": "topics",
      "id": "sports",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Sports",
        "show-role-title": null,
        "parent-topic-id": null,
        "created-at": "2017-04-16T21:19:25.000Z",
        "updated-at": null
      },
      "links": {
        "self": "/topics/sports"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, considering that `sports` is already in `data` but *also* related to `basketball`, is it valid to also attach it as an `included` record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you should be having two resources `/topics` and `/parentTopic` and it is valid to have the same copy of data in both primary object and included object provided that your request has such necessity. In your case the request will be `/topics?include=parentTopic`

According to [JSON API spec](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes), include is not mandatory. My suggestion is that `/topics` is fine and you can refer parent-topic data from `/topics` relationship (depends on client framework) and if you query particular resource record, you can add inclusion `/topics/sports-basketball?include=parentTopic`